# DOM not updating when model updates

Tags: javascript, rivets.js

I am using Rivets.js to make a countdown timer. The countdown timer appears initially, but it does not decrement each time setInterval is called. Why?

**Javascript:**

```
function startTimer(minutes) {
    var countdown = (60 * minutes)-1;
    rivets.bind($('#timer'), { countdown: countdown });

    var timer = setInterval(function() {

        countdown--;

        if (countdown < 0) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="timer">{countdown}</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the rivets update function be inside the interval function?

Comment: do you mean `rivets.bind`? that's not really an update function, it just binds the model to the data. but i did try putting it inside setInterval with no luck.

Comment: Still how would rivets know that countdown is decreasing?

Comment: Isn't that what one-way binding does? `One-way binders simply update the DOM when a model property changes (model-to-view only). ` I've gotten one-way binding to work fine in other instances.

Comment: Change `bind` to `call`. Bind only binds it so it can be executed later, call actually binds it and executes it immediately.

Comment: `undefined is not a function`. I don't think `call` is a rivets method.

Comment: For reference: Mouser confused rivets' bind method with Javascript bind method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind rivets with an object, otherwise the binding gets lost when you change the variable:

```
function startTimer(minutes) {
    var countdownObj = {};
    var countdown = (60 * minutes)-1;
    countdownObj.cd = countdown;
    rivets.bind($('#timer'), { countdown: countdownObj });

    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        countdownObj.cd--;
        if (countdownObj.cd < 0) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

And in your HTML:

```
<div id="timer">{countdown.cd}</div>
```

Check [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YFBHDtCnakoewZNUCIVi)

Comment: perfect thanks! Rivets works on javascript arrays too, so i thought it would work on ints.